# How do I take slice from an array position to end of the array?

Tags: arrays, scala

How do I get an array of array with elements like this? Is there an inbuilt scala api that can provide this value (without using combinations)?

e.g

```
val inp = Array(1,2,3,4)
```

Output

```
Vector(
  Vector((1,2), (1,3), (1,4)), 
  Vector((2,3), (2,4)), 
  Vector((3,4))
)
```

My answer is below. I feel that there should be an elegant answer than this in scala.

```
  val inp = Array(1,2,3,4)
  val mp = (0 until inp.length - 1).map( x => {
    (x + 1 until inp.length).map( y => {
      (inp(x),inp(y))
    })
  })

  print(mp)
```

+Edit
Added combination constraint.

Comment: I noticed that my original answer had made an assumption the elements are unique and sorted. I've added a new version for the other case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

**Note** This answer is OK only if the elements in the Seq are unique and sorted (according to `<`). See edit for the more general case.

With

```
val v = a.toVector
```

and by foregoing `combinations`, I can choose tuples instead and not have to cast at the end

```
for (i <- v.init) yield { for (j <- v if i < j) yield (i, j) }
```

or

```
v.init.map(i => v.filter(i < _).map((i, _)))
```

Not sure if there's a performance hit for using init on vector

**EDIT**

For non-unique elements, we can use the indices

```
val v = a.toVector.zipWithIndex
for ((i, idx) <- v.init) yield { for ((j, jdx) <- v if idx < jdx) yield (i, j) }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `combinations(2)` and `groupBy()` on the first element (`0`) of each combination will give you the values and structure you want. Getting the result as a `Vector[Vector]]` will require some conversion using `toVector`

```
scala> inp.combinations(2).toList.groupBy(a => a(0)).values
res11: Iterable[List[Array[Int]]] = MapLike.DefaultValuesIterable
(
 List(Array(2, 3), Array(2, 4)),
 List(Array(1, 2), Array(1, 3), Array(1, 4)),
 List(Array(3, 4))
)
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without combinations? Combinations are always frowned upon!!

Comment: @RaviR why's that?

Comment: @RaviR You can do it with recursion and pattern matching if you like.

Comment: I don’t know. Every time I propose a solution with combinations, people feel that it is computationally more intensive. I don’t know if there is any runtime diff though